# Tableau Address Geocoding

Tags: tableau-api

I want to build a dashboard where I can search by any address in the U.S., have it geocoded by Tableau, and then filter a dataset based on a 1-5 mile radius from that address. Does Tableau have the capability to do this, or do I need a third party app to accomodate the address search feature / geocoding.

Comment: Have you tried tableau custom geo coding, Also version of tableau you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Tableau's built-in logic only supports the identification of things like cities and zip codes.  If you want more granular location visuals (street addresses and such), you will need geocode yourself prior to building your datasource.

[onlinehelp.tableau.com](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_data.html?tocpath=Design%20Views%20and%20Analyze%20Data%7CBuild%20Map%20Views%7CBring%20Location%20Data%20into%20Tableau%7C_____1)

In the past, I've done this with some simple python code and ArcGIS:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import ArcGIS    

#csv with street addresses, cities, states, and zip
file_loc = "C:/Documents/data.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file_loc, na_values=None,
                 dtype = {'STREET': object, 'CITY': object, 'STATE': object, 'ZIP': object})

df = df.fillna('')

street = df['STREET'].map(str)    
city = df['CITY'].map(str)    
state = df['STATE'].map(str)    
zip = df['ZIP'].map(str)

addr = street + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip

df['ADDRESS'] = addr    
addresses = df['ADDRESS'].unique()

geolocator = ArcGIS()

addr_list = []

for a in addresses:
    temp_dict = {}
    loc = geolocator.geocode(a,timeout = 5)
    if loc:
        temp_dict['LAT'] = loc.latitude
        temp_dict['LONG'] = loc.longitude
        temp_dict['ADDR'] = loc.address
        temp_dict['ADDRESS'] = a
    else:
        temp_dict['LAT'] = None
        temp_dict['LONG'] = None
        temp_dict['ADDR'] = None
        temp_dict['ADDRESS'] = a
    addr_list.append(temp_dict)

addr_df = pd.DataFrame(addr_list)

df = df.merge(addr_df, on='ADDRESS', how='left')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('outdate.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```